# Not working SMTP_validateEmail on live site using php

Tags: php, cakephp

hey My code is working fine on my local server but not working on live site.
I used class SMTP_validateEmail.class.php file to implement the email validation. Please help me as soon as possible. What we need to do to execute  this.

For invalid email it is working fine but for correct email it is not working fine.

============for smtp_validateEmail.class.php=====

https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/

//===check_mail.php===

```
<?php

/**
 * Example 1
 * Validate a single Email via SMTP
 */


// include SMTP Email Validation Class

require_once('smtp_validateEmail.class.php');

// the email to validate

$email = $_POST['name'];
// an optional sender

$sender = $_POST['name'];
// instantiate the class

$SMTP_Validator = new SMTP_validateEmail();
// turn on debugging if you want to view the SMTP transaction

//$SMTP_Validator->debug = true;
// do the validation

$results = $SMTP_Validator->validate(array($email), $sender);


// send email?

if ($results[$email]) {
 echo 1; 
} else {
  echo 0; 
}


?>
```

Comment: you should paste the code you are using and the error message you are getting

Comment: I am using zend engine for this.

Comment: First check that File included or not

Comment: both files are included.

Comment: What version of PHP is running on live and local servers?  What operating systems?

Comment: Looking at the source code of the validator, it actually does DNS validation on the email address domain name.  I imagine the problem lies there.  You might want to do some debugging inside `smtp_validateEmail.class.php` itself.

Comment: If all else fails, just change that validator out for something more reliable, like sending a confirmation email.  DNS validation for email addresses really isn't necessary, and if you want to be absolutely certain, you'll have to use a confirmation email anyway.

Comment: I am using exact same code i.e. the code in the question along with the one here https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/source/browse/trunk/smtp_validateEmail.class.php?r=2  but I can't even connect on localhost. Any known issues that can cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue but I tried to change the `$nameserver` array values in `SMTP_validateEmail.class.php` to my web hosting sever's IP address and now it is working fine.

If your server has any other port number for `SMTP` like Google then replace the existing port number with it.

Hope it will work for you too.